# How is this returning 8? I expect 6

Tags: python, function, for-loop, printing, return

```
def power(num, x=1):
    result = 1
    for i in range(x): 
        result = result * num
    return result
print(power(num=2, x=3))
```

This is a Python function with a `for` loop in it that is supposed to print out the power of something but I am not sure how this code is working because the result is `result * num`.

Can someone please explain how this is returning 8 as answer, because if I multiply `num` with `result`, I get 6?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! The `power` function revolves around the for-loop.
Calling it with `power(num=2, x=3)` results in repeating the for-loop three
times (from x).

First time: `result = 1 * 2  ==> 2`

Second time: `result = 2 * 2 ==> 4`

Third time: `result = 4 * 2 ==> 8`

By contrast, if you were expecting 6, try changing the statement in the
for-loop to `result = result + num`. See?

Answer (score 0):

See, `power(num=2, x=3)` are the parameters provided. `def (num, x=1)`. It means if no value is given for `x`, then take it as 1.

```
def power(num, x=1):
    result = 1
    for i in range(x): 
        result = result * num
    return result
print(power(num=2, x=3))
```

In here, you are iterating over the value of `x` which is 3 in the case.
Here is what it is doing. The `range` function returns all numbers in the specific range. So when `range(x)` means `range(3)` as `x=3` and then it will iterate over it.

It is basically assigning the product of `result` and `num` which is 3.
This is the output when you add `print(result,num)` inside the `for` loop.

```
1 2
2 2
4 2
8
```

In the first case, the value of `result` was 1. It was multiplied by 2 and reassigned to `result` like `result=result*num`. Therefore the new value of `result` is `2 x 1` = 2. Then again it is doing the same thing, taking the new value of `result`, multiplying by `num` and reassigning the value to `result`. This will continue until the loop ends.

So it will be:

```
1*2=2 #=== Reassigned to result
2*2=4 #=== Reassigned to result
4*2=8 #=== Reassigned to result

#=== End of loop ===
```

And at the last, when the loop ends, `return result` will return the value of `result` which is 8.